# Specify colors for each link in a force directed network, networkD3::forceNetwork()

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, networkd3

The question is to specify two different colors based on the Value or weight of the link using `networkD3::forceNetwork` in R. For example, `Blue` for the weight of links more than 1, `dark` for the weight of links less than 1.

Example code, copied from [here](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/) (the `forceNetwork` section):

```
library(networkD3)
# Load data
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

# Plot
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
        Source = "source", Target = "target",
        Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
        Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)
```

A d3-js related question is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/fs4u0392Eno) (I know nothing about JS so far).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just had the same problem working with `networkD3`.
You can do that by providing a vector depending on the values of `MisLinks$value` using the `ifelse` function:

```
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
         Source = "source", Target = "target",
         Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
         Group = "group", opacity = 0.8,
         linkColour = ifelse(MisLinks$value > 1, "blue","black"))
```

This solution does not depend on knowing `javascript`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: can we add a legend based on the link color ? Not replacing an existing legend. Something like. 2 legends one for the nodes and another for the link color ?

Answer (score 7):

I think you should be able to pass a javascript function wrapped in `JS` to `linkColour` to get colors based on the values in MisLinks.  For example, return blue links for values > 1 and red for values <= 1.

```
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
             Source = "source", Target = "target",
             Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.8,
             linkColour = JS('function(l) { return l.value > 1 ? "#00F" : "#F00" }'))
```

Comment: in this example is it possible to use a different attribute for color?  so, use `value` for width of the edge and `colocated` for color?  I tried passing an attribute called `colocated` in addition to `source`, `target` and `value` and changed the code to `linkColour = JS('function(l) { return l.colocated > 0 ? "#00F" : "#F00" }')`.  I get the following error: `cannot coerce class ""JS_EVAL"" to a data.frame`.

Comment: possibly a related question whereby one must colour the nodes with pre designated colours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793947/r-colouring-scheme-in-networkd3-vs-igraph?noredirect=1#comment65115769_38793947

Comment: @ironv it seems linkColour parameter no longer supports JS, while it worked well before. However, Joseah's answer works.

Comment: Is it possible to add a legend based on `linkColour` argument?